How to set macOS Sonoma Dark Mode to work to your schedule?
Using the “Auto” option for appearance switches from light to dark based on sunset and sunrise times. I want to set a custom schedule. For instance, time to time for light, otherwise it's dark. Or, turn on dark mode 4 hours before sunset each day.
I came across an article that put forth Night Shift as the solution, but it's from 2021 and does not seem to work any more.

You could use Shortcuts to control the dark/light appearance using "Set Appearance" (e.g. Is there a way of toggling dark mode using the Shortcuts app?). But you'd need something that triggers this automatically because this functionality doesn't seem to be built-into Shortcuts, but I found this apparently free (has in-app purchases though, so maybe they make you pay for some features, or only offer a free trial) Shortery app that looks like it can be used to accomplish that without too much trouble using "Time" as a trigger.

Alternatively I found this Medium article which uses daily Calendar events to open an Automator application that runs the Shortcut. This is done by creating a recurring calendar event and setting a custom alert on it with "Open file" selected:

Instead of using Automator, you could select File > Add to Dock when editing the Shortcut, and then that will create an application in ~/Applications/YourShortcutName which you could link to the calendar event.
I've tried out this Calendar approach (Sonoma, 14.5, but I'd guess it'd work the same on older versions as well) and it worked well. You may want to include a Notification step or something in the Shortcut. You could either have one Shortcut that sets the appearance to light, and another that sets it to dark, with separate calendar events, or you could put the logic inside a single Shortcut.
Here's a working example of a possible combined shortcut:

(Note I originally had "10:00" as the start time, but that was being interpreted as 10 pm despite my system being set to 24 hour time, so seems it's best to just put AM for ambiguous times).
Also, you may not want these daily events cluttering up your calendar, but you can create a new calendar, then just uncheck it from the list so it isn't displayed.
Note however that if your Mac isn't running when the Calendar alert fires I don't think this will work. But you could also have set up your custom Shortcut app to "Open at Login". That would not run when you're just unlocking the Mac though, so then might just have to use Shortery.
